# generic interfaces with reified methods

Tags: generics, interface, kotlin, inline, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have several objects to reinterpreter memory:

```
interface reinterpreter<T> {
    operator fun get(index: Int): T
    operator fun set(index: Int, value: T): Any
}

object vec1bData : reinterpreter<Vec1b> {    
    override operator fun get(index: Int) = Vec1b(data, index * Vec1b.size)    
    override fun set(index: Int, value: Vec1b) = value.to(data, index * Vec1b.size)    
}
```

but when I type

```
inline fun <reified T> data():reinterpreter<T> = when (T::class.java) {    
        Vec1b::class.java -> vec1bData    
}
```

I get:

> required `reinterpeter<T>`, but found `vec1bData`

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `vec1bData` is not a valid substitute for `reinterpeter<T>`, because the `T` of `vec1bData` is not generic, but set to `Vec1b`.

That means, taking just the function signature `fun <reified T> data(): reinterpreter<T>`, you must return a `reinterpreter<T>`. Instead you return a `vec1bData`, which is of type `reinterpreter<Vec1b>` instead of `reinterpreter<T>`.

Comment: Casting will help here, in Kotlin it's done with the `as` keyword.